# AngularJS smart-table search within multiple columns

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Smart-table has a built in functionality to search through all columns (st-search) or through one desired column (st-search="'firstName'). Is it possible to do a search within several columns (not all)?
Example: if I have table like this: name, nickname, address with such data:

1. John, JJ, Some address
2. Steve, John, also address
3. Jane, Jane, John-village

and do a search for 'John' only first two columns should be as result.
Is it possible?

Comment: I suggested a way to solve the problem. Take a look at the answer!

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem and I solved using the hints in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442331/filtering-filter-matching-values-from-list-of-objects-excluding-unnecessary-p/32458981).

Smart Table doc says:

> The `stSetFilter` replaces the filter used when searching through Smart
>   Table. When the default behavior for `stSearch` does not meet your
>   demands, like in a select where one entry is a substring of another,
>   use a custom filter to achieve your goals.

and:

> Note that `st-safe-src` is required for the select to properly display
>   all distinct elements in the collection. Should this be omitted, the
>   select would only contain values from elements visible in table, also
>   affected by paging.

You can declare your own filter inside table element in HTML:

```
<table ... st-set-filter="myCustomFilter" class="table table-striped">
```

...and your can customize your filter (in your app) through a predicate function. It could work in this way:

```
// filter method, creating `myCustomFilter` a globally
// available filter in our module
.filter('myCustomFilter', ['$filter', function($filter) {

  // function that's invoked each time Angular runs $digest()
  return function(input, predicate) {
    searchValue = predicate['$'];
    //console.log(searchValue);
    var customPredicate = function(value, index, array) {
      console.log(value);

      // if filter has no value, return true for each element of the input array
      if (typeof searchValue === 'undefined') {
        return true;
      }

      var p0 = value['name'].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase());
      var p1 = value['nickname'].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase());
      if (p0 > -1 || p1 > -1) {
        // return true to include the row in filtered resultset
        return true;
      } else {
        // return false to exclude the row from filtered resultset
        return false;
      }
    }

    //console.log(customPredicate);
    return $filter('filter')(input, customPredicate, false);
  }
}])
```

I made this little [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2bohkcq3NdhTCp1ilsit?p=preview) to see the filter in action

Answer (score 1):

Nope, a workaround is to create you own directive which require the table controller and call its api twice (as the search get added)

```
directive('stSearch', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        scope: {
            predicate: '=?stSearch'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            var tableCtrl = ctrl;

            // view -> table state
            element.bind('input', function (evt) {
                evt = evt.originalEvent || evt;
                tableCtrl.search(evt.target.value, 'column1');
                tableCtrl.search(evt.target.value, 'column2');
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

you'll find more details in the [stSearch direcitve](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/blob/master/src/stSearch.js)

Comment: I played with a part of code you suggested, but it looks like It is filtering and not searching through multiple columns.  Or maybe I am missing something :) Take a look at my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j5QzGBExnfaCQdYupdk1?p=preview)
What I am expecting in example is to get result with three rows (1,4;4,1 and 1,1), when searching for '1' in both columns.

Comment: I have tested this code in Angular 1.5.x and it fails to search through multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by creating the new search enabled table and combining the fields that you might be showing in one column. 
example:if you have IdNo1 and IdNo2 as view fileds in One column, you can combine them to add the new element in the table array.

**View :**

**table injection:**

```
table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowSearchCollection"
```

**Search injection:**

```
input type="search" ng-model="idSearch" st-search="idSearch"
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.rowSearchCollection = [];
vm.searchEnabledTable = function(tableDetails) {
    //$scope.rowSearchCollection = angular.copy(tableDetails); 
    var deferred = $q.defer();              
      if(_.isArray(tableDetails)) {
          _.each(tableDetails, function(element, index, list) {
            $scope.rowSearchCollection[index] = angular.copy(element);
            $scope.rowSearchCollection[index].idSearch = element.IdNo1+','+element.IdNo2;


          });
          deferred.resolve("DATA_PROCESSED");
      } else {
          deferred.reject("NOT_ARRAY");
      }             
      return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with stSetFilter is that the new filter will be to all the
searchs (st-search) that you will use in the table.

Another idea: 
If your data rowCollection is not too big,
in the javascript in the init() of the page do something like:

self.rowCollection.forEach(function (element) {

element.NameForFilter = element.name+ ' ' + element.nickName;
});

and then in the input of the th: 
st-search=NameForFilter

Answer (score -1):

try st-search="{{firstName + nickname}}". I tried with smart table v2.1.6 and seems working.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It's like st-search without parameters SO you search in everything

Comment: I tried this solution. As noted earlier it returns everything. Would be a nice feature but currently this does nothing in Smart Table other than search all.