# Angualarjs smart table search particular columns

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

i have used this documentation [smart table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/)

```
<form>
    <label for="predicate">selected predicate:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="predicate" ng-model="selectedPredicate" ng-options="predicate for predicate in predicates"></select>
</form>
<table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
        <th st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
        <th st-sort="birthDate">birth date</th>
        <th st-sort="balance">balance</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input st-search="{{firstName}},{{lastName}}" placeholder="search for firstname" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
        </th>
        <th colspan="3">
            <input st-search placeholder="global search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <input st-search="{{selectedPredicate}}" placeholder="bound predicate" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
        <td>{{row.firstName | uppercase}}</td>
        <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.birthDate | date}}</td>
        <td>{{row.balance | currency}}</td>
        <td><a ng-href="mailto:{{row.email}}">email</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i have used st-search search for particular column . it is working fine but two column not working. can you help me? i need search two column only

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently no way to achieve this directly with the built smart-table.

You can use a directive like suggested here :
[AngularJS smart-table search within multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791998/angularjs-smart-table-search-within-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I have another idea for others who have the same problem: 
If your data rowCollection is not too big,
in the javascript in the `init()` of the page do something like:

```
self.rowCollection.forEach(function (element) {

  element.NameForFilter = element.firstName+ ' ' + element.lastName;  
});
```

and then in the input of the th:

```
st-search=NameForFilter
```